# File Size with Tabs vs Spaces

Tags: coding-style

Is is true that file size with Tab Indentation is much smaller than the one's with spaces?

In the article below it shows Space indented file size to be about 18% more than Tab indented files.

Source:
http://madskristensen.net/post/performance-of-tabs-vs-spaces-in-html-files

Comment: Yes. A tab is one character in size. Each space is also one character, so if you indent using 4 spaces it takes 4 characters, and 8 spaces would consume 8 characters.  This is absolute common sense; why do you need to even ask?

Answer (score 4):

Well it makes sense. The tab is a single ascii character whereas 4 spaces are, well, 4 ascii characters. Over many indents, that can definitely add up

Answer (score 3):

The analysis is flawed in that it doesn't consider the ways files are stored. The first example on the source article shows 1403 (tabs) and 1703 (spaces), but both would take up the same storage space on modern drives (4096 block size), for instance.

Of course, space indentation takes more space, but the question of "how much" is more complicated than comparing byte counts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I tried once to replace all 4-spaces with a tab. I went from 8822 kB to 7610 KB in a file of 337 lines of code. ~1.18 MB gained.